# How to get the biggest value in any consecutive range

Tags: mysql, window-functions, recursive-query, gaps-and-islands, dense-rank

Consider the following values in an indexed column of unsigned integers:

```
1
2
3
3
2
4
6
8
9
```

For any number provided, I want to get the biggest value in its consecutive range (continue stepping forward while the next consecutive number exists).

For example, suppose we are provided with the input of `2`; the consecutive values of `3` and `4` do exist in the list (regardless of their order), but `5` doesn't exist; therefore our consecutive range would be `2,3,4`; thus the expected value would be `4`: the biggest value in this consecutive range; having provided with any of `1`, `3`, or `4`, should also yield `4`. Thus:

```
input           expected output
-------------------------------
1,2,3,4                       4  -- any value of the input yields 4
5                             5  -- the input value doesn't even exist in the list
6                             6  -- it's the only value
7                             7  -- the input value doesn't even exist in the list
8,9                           9
```

So, how to get the biggest value in any consecutive range using MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a recursive CTE:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT x FROM tablename WHERE x = ?
  UNION 
  SELECT t.x
  FROM tablename t INNER JOIN cte c
  ON t.x = c.x + 1
)
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(x), ?) x FROM cte;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=38f23a81972ea47a326fdcfa1d8354e3).

Or, with `DENSE_RANK()` window function:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN x = rn THEN x END), ?) x
FROM (
  SELECT x, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY x) + ? rn
  FROM tablename
  WHERE x > ? AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE x = ?)
) t
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7410e1c49d057de665eca71b0bf36403).

Replace `?` with the `input` value that you want.

Comment: This is genius! 

Answer (score 1):

This might be a *gap isolation problem* which might need to use the window function to solve and CTE recursive to solve it.

first, we can try to use CTE recursive generator number call `startnum` range from the smallest number to the biggest of data (from our sample are `1`,`9`), because there is some missing number between them.

Next step we might calculate a `grp` that is gap-and-island problem feature logic.

The logic might be as below.

> continuous(overlapping) data is that a set `(continuous range of sequence) - (values ​​based on a certain order of conditions sequence)` yields the same grouping.

so we can use

- continuous range of sequence: startNum
- values ​​based on a certain order: `dense_rank` window function.

using this logic we might get a `grp` column as [sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d7b485e35bdc50b35d4d2debb24333cc)

**Query #1**

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS(
   SELECT MIN(val) startNum, MAX(val) endNum
   FROM T
   UNION ALL
   SELECT startNum + 1,endNum
   FROM cte
   WHERE startNum + 1 <= endNum
)
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT startNum) input,
       MAX(startNum) 'expected output'
FROM (
  SELECT val,
     startNum ,
     startNum - cast(dense_rank() OVER(ORDER BY val)as signed) grp
  FROM cte t1
  LEFT JOIN T t2
  ON t1.startNum = t2.val
) t1
GROUP BY grp
ORDER BY 2;
```

| input | expected output |
| --- | --- |
| 1,2,3,4 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 6 | 6 |
| 7 | 7 |
| 8,9 | 9 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/75ERdyRaZQHh1sHqmNueeq/1)

Comment: This is amazing, thank you D-Shih; but I actually don't want to get them all at once, having provided with any number should only output the expected result (only a one-to-one query, the "input" value will be injected into query by a higher-level language); and lastly, the query outputs `7` for both `5` and `7`; while it should only return `7` for `7` (and thus only `5` for `5`) as in the OP.

Comment: @goodUser Oops, I didn't see the mistake I fixed it on my answer and I will write more explain about it

Comment: WoW! This is tremendous!! Thank you so much D-Shih! Only this last thing: how to provide a single value (e.g. `2` or `3` or whatever) to run the query _only for the range starting from the provided value_? (the query runs for the whole table, that is not only overkill for my need case, but would be inefficient for my big data)